# Pavel Tsatsouline StrongFirst program and endorsing kettlebells and bodyweight

Tags: strength, bodyweight-exercises

Isn't it a contradiction to aim for increasing strength first, and then ,focusing on kettlebells and bodyweight exercises?

Wouldn't the first imply that you should be using heavy (or heavier) weights? Kettlebells and bodyweight seem to be to be fine for endurance training. Maybe they are useful for beginning with very poor form.

But I can't see how you could avoid reaching a plateau pretty soon, if you are planning to get stronger.

Am I wrong here in assuming that it's difficult to make kettlebell and bodyweight exercises progressively challenging?

Comment: The body responds to resistance, and resistance alone. It doesn’t matter what form that resistance takes (iron, bands, body weight).

Comment: @JustSnilloc: no doubt about that. But, you'll reach a maximum weight (that is, your weight) quite fast, and won't be able to increase gradually the resistance from there.

Comment: Right, but the thing about body weight exercises is that you don’t do the same exercise to make it harder, you modify it or do another exercise altogether. Using pushups as an example you could start with incline pushups, then do regular pushups, and then do decline pushups. Or you could do one arm pushups, one leg pushups, there are all sorts of ways to increase the resistance without increasing your weight.